# Use TreeSet to sort JList

Tags: java, jlist, hashset, treeset

I'm doing an assignment where I'm making a program that generates 20 random numbers and puts them in an arraylist, a hashset and a treeset. It is supposed to show those numbers in JList1. Then, I am going to use HashSet to display unique numbers only, and TreeSet to display the numbers sorted. I made three JLists, and made one function for each of them to update the GUI (there's probably an easier way to do this, but thats all I could come up with due to me being quite new to java). So, for example my updateGUI function used to display the arraylist in my JList looks like this:

```
public void updateGUI(JList someList, ArrayList<Integer> anyarraylist){
        DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();
        for (Object  s : anyarraylist) {
            m.addElement(s);
        }
        someList.setModel(m);
    }
```

I then call that function when I press a button by using ActionEvent:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    generateNumbers();

    this.updateGUI(this.numbers1, numberlist);
```

Where generateNumbers is my function to generate 20 random numbers, numbers1 is my first JList and numberlist is the name of my arraylist.

I did pretty much the exact same thing for HashSet to display a JList with unique numbers, and it worked. However, I then tried to do the same for TreeSet, which gave me a "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"-error. The function looks like this:

```
    public void oppdaterGUI3(JList someList, TreeSet<Integer> anysortedlist){
    DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();
    for (Object  s : anysortedlist) {
        m.addElement(s);
    }
    someList.setModel(m);
}
```

Why doesn't this work? I thought TreeSet would work the same way as HashSet. Any help is appreciated. I can post the full error and code if necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot really expect a comprehensive and meaningful answer with so much information missing. Please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

I formulate the following as answer, though information is lacking.

Look at the stacktrace of the NullPointerException. It gives the line number where it happened.

It might be that the TreeSet is defined twice, once as local variable. Or there is one case where a copy of the tree set had to happen too. Something like that.

You can debug it, using break points. Walk through all uses of the tree set var and one other var.

For a bit more responsive GUI use the following pattern.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()) {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            generateNumbers();
            /*MyClass.this.*/ updateGUI(this.numbers1, numberlist);
        }
    });
}
```